# MS Word not trusted by Outlook?

Tags: security, ms-word, outlook, mailmerge

- a Delphi app automating Word mail merge and emailing via Outlook (Office 2007).
- Windows XP2
- Anti Virus Software Status -Valid
- Trust Center Programmatic Access NEVER WARN ME.
- (A different app not using Word but using Outlook emails without warning).

Yet Outlook Security Guard Warning Messages appear. 
2 alerts per email x 700 email addresses = One angry customer.

Why? Without using a 3rd parry add-in, is there a way round this?
Is there a way to merge one record and the run some delphi code then another record merge? I can then bypass Outlook altogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook has no idea where the call comes from. Outlook VBA and COM add-in are explicilty trusted, any external code is not.
You will not see the prompt if you have up-to-date antivirus software. 
 
Otherwise your option are listed at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 
In your case (Mail Merge), try to do the mail merge to a file, then mail the files in your code using the workarounds listed at the URL above.

Comment: 1) av is valid as checked in the Outlook Trust Center.2) I cannot see an option in the type lib for destination MailMergeTOFile. Are you suggesting Create a datasouce of 1 record, Merge, Save email and loop to next record? Messy but maybe....

Comment: I am no Word Object Model expert, but you should be able to output your mail merge to a file instead of e-mail: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301656?wa=wsignin1.0